# Inserting a date into a table adds extra timestamp with it

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I am trying to insert a column that is in date format such like 2019-09-25 but whenever I run the query it adds the timestamp (2019-08-15T00:00:00.0000000) to it even though I have defined the column to be 'date' format. How can I make sure it only shows the date?

Comment: If the column is truly a date type then you've got a conversion somewhere in the query. What tool are you using?

Comment: You could also try adding a date that includes a time component. I'm guessing that when you pull the data back out the time will have been stripped off.

Comment: I am using azure sql database, and somehow it defaults the date to show with the timestamp.

Comment: I don't know of Azure has some kind of default output setting. What does this show?: `select cast(getdate() as date)`

Answer (score 0):

There are few settings which sets by Oracle on your behalf. One of them is date/time format. Your default NLS_DATE_FORMAT is currently set up to return timestamp also along with date. You only need to alter your session to return only date while fetching column with DATE datatype -

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
```

Comment: I am using Azure Sql database, so this isn't working

Answer (score 0):

Check like below-

```
-- FUNCTION for Getting Azure DateTime as per our Time Zone
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.udf_getdate()
RETURNS DATETIME
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Current_DateTime DATETIME
    SELECT @Current_DateTime=SYSDATETIMEOFFSET() AT TIME ZONE 'India Standard Time'  -- IST Format.(give your timezone here)
    RETURN @Current_DateTime 
END
GO

-- DECLARE LOCAL VARIABLE AND GET THE RESULTS AS EXPECTED AND USE IT
DECLARE @CurrentDateTime DATETIME,@CurrentDate DATE;
SELECT @CurrentDateTime = dbo.udf_getdate();
SELECT @CurrentDate = CAST(@CurrentDateTime AS DATE);

SELECT @CurrentDateTime AS [CurrentDateTime],@CurrentDate AS [CurrentDate];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot of trouble with this, and i came to conclusion that it is working properly but the thing is that query editor on Azure portal is in preview mode.

In pictures below you can see that when I inserted a value that has some hours/minutes/sec into a column that is of type 'date'

Once I try to read the same data, hours/minutes/secs will be set to 0, which means it wrote the correct value to the table (only year-month-day), but problem comes when that value needs to be displayed.

[image]
[image]

Long story short:
Basically i think Azure portal can't display correct value because it is in preview. (but correct value is inserted into database)

in picture below is how Azure portal query editor is displaying data:

[image]

and if you export that database, and import it into a local SQL server, same data will be displayed as

[image]

Comment: So does this answer the question?

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: Sorry for complicating it up :)
I've edited the comment to be more understandable